# How to properly test the Mail object in rspec

Tags: rspec

In my reading of rspec, it sounds like doing something like...

```
expect_any_instance_of(Mail).to receive(:deliver)
```

...should cause rspec to replace the deliver method with it's own so that the deliver method isn't actually called.  But in my case when I do that I get the following error in my test which leads me to believe that it is still being called.

```
 Failure/Error: task.send_email_alert('test', dummy)
     Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
       Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25
```

Here's my method

```
def send_email_alert(alert_body, alert)
  mail = Mail.new do
    from alert.send_emails_from
    to alert.email_address
    subject 'New job posted from ' + alert.job_board_name
    body alert_body
  end
  mail.deliver!
end
```

And here's the test.

```
context 'send_email_alert' do
    it 'creates an email and calls the deliver method' do
      dummy = OpenStruct.new(send_emails_from: 'test@test.com', job_board_name: 'test', email_address: 'test@test.com')
      expect(Mail).to receive(:deliver).and_return(true)
      task.send_email_alert('test', dummy)
    end
end
```

Comment: "I get the following error" Where is this error?

Comment: Doh, sorry, I forgot to paste that one in.  Original question edited to include error.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Well as I said, my understanding was that rspec replaced the actual method with a fake one but in this case it appears to be calling the actual method.  Am I doing something wrong that it's not doing that or am I wrong in my understanding?  Ultimately I don't want to actually call the deliver method, I just want to make sure it was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've stubbed `deliver`, but you did not stub `deliver!`, which is the method you called. They are separate methods.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem.  Thanks!